# Limit Jackson REST API's calls

Tags: java, web-services, rest, api, jackson

I'm building a REST Api using Jackson.

As many standard APIs do, this is an interface between a front-end and various resources (databases and processing engines on different environments).

GUI -> REST API -> Databases, HDFS, Hive etc.

What is a way to shield these resources from overloading?

What would be a good design to limit the number of calls that my API does to these services but yet still "handle" the calls from the front end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow below aproaches to shield these resources from overloading

1) You can put up a in-memory cache over the service layer that interacts with databases resources.So these will reduces.

2)You can throttle your api calls.Therefore you can limit the no of api calls from a particular user.
Reference - https://adayinthelifeof.nl/2014/05/28/throttle-your-api-calls-ratelimitbundle/